# How do you extract packages installed by pip and import onto another computer with no internet?

Tags: python, pip

There is a project in another laptop which is unable to connect to the internet (Lan only), so `pip install requests` is impossible.

main.py:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('http://localhost/')
```

__

I've tried to copy `certifi`, `chardet`, `idna`, `requests`, `urllib3` from `site-packages` and import without a problem when the dependency is in the same folder

```
Project
├── certifi
├── chardet
├── idna
├── main.py
├── requests
└── urllib3
```

__

But it can't be imported when dependency in subdirectory `supportFiles`

main.py:

`import supportFiles.requests`

Output : no module named urllib3...

```
Project                         
    ├── main.py
    └── supportFiles
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── certifi
        ├── chardet
        ├── idna
        ├── requests
        └── urllib
```

what should I do?

Comment: I would figure out why you can't `pip install` packages instead of doing this.

Comment: Why are you copying files from site-packages? You could solve your problem with PYTHONPATH but I question why you are doing that. There is probably a better way.

Comment: That is the question(and the answer) I want. Thanks! Production env should not be connected to Internet.

Answer (score 7):

Use `pip download` (with older versions of pip, `pip install --download <dir> <package-name>`):

```
pip download requests
```

which will download the package and dependencies to current folder. Copy the packages to the laptop and then pip install using:

```
pip install <path-to-requests-package-file>
```

Comment: The package appears as "UNKNOWN" after installed. Any idea why?

Answer (score -2):

You can use [`virtualenv`](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) to create an environment on the computer with an internet connection, install all required packages using the activated virtualenv

Then copy the folder with the prepared environment to the target laptop.
Active the environment on the target laptop.

Comment: A virtualenv has full paths coded into its activate file (at least it did with older versions) so moving from one machine to another can be problematic.  As well, any packages that contain compiled code may not work properly depending on architecture, versions, and dependencies.